# File move in Perl that stops the current script?

Tags: perl, mv

how can I do this `mv ($file $new_file/$1) or die("Errors 2")`;

so it would stop the script in terminal if the file is not found?

otherwise it keeps repeating and repeating and I need to restart putty session so i would be able to type something

Comment: What is repeating? There's no loop here. Also, `mv()` is not a Perl function. The Perl function that renames a file is called `rename()`.

Comment: the loop is around the function, so basically it does not move the correct file and thats why it keeps repeating, so I would like to show error and stop the script.

Comment: Besides the fact that `mv` is not a perl function, and you are missing a comma in the argument list, there is nothing wrong with this code. It is the code surrounding it -- which you are not showing -- that is responsible.

Comment: Also, an infinite loop can be stopped with `CTRL-C`. You do not need to close putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 use autodie;
 rename($file, "$dir/$newname")
```

- If it fails to rename for any reason it'll die. If the file isn't there it obviously failed to rename and that will be caught as well.

Comment: mv can also autodie. `use File::Copy qw(mv); use autodie qw(:all mv); mv $file, "$new_file/$1";`

Answer (score 0):

What about this then:

```
if ( -f $file ) {
  rename($file, "$dir/$newname")
    or die("Could not rename '$file' to '$dir/$newname'");
} else {
  die("File '$file' does not exist");
}
```

Please read the manual for the `rename()` function to see its limitations (`perldoc -f rename`) and what you might want to do about it (e.g., use `move()` from the `File::Copy` module).

Comment: That introduces a very slight race condition where the file could disappear between the `-f $file` and the `rename()` call.

Comment: Include `"$!"` in the error message and you won't need the if/else.

Comment: @cansp Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @CanSpice, in which case it will die when `rename()` fails rather than in the `else`. Not a big problem. It would be better, of course, to use `$!` as @Kieth suggests.